# Facebook Registeration for bada 1.1

Tags: facebook, authentication, bada

I have made an app in bada 2.0 in which I have implement facebook and It works fine.

But when I use the same code for bada 1.1, it doesn't work.

I have:

1. registered the app for 1.1 both on http://developer.bada.com
2. used the downloaded manifest file in app and also register the app on https://developers.facebook.com
3. used the application key and secret in the app

But my app after authenticating successfully doesn't proceed and emulator shows loading continues without showing any error message in the log.

Can any one tell me whether it is a server side problem or I have done something wrong?

I have followed the same steps for the registeration as for bada 2.0 app and 2.0 app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I there might be some issue in Bada server. Some time it faces some outages. Try after some time..also you should use a different manifest file from Bada developer site for 1.1.